# Will a PowerEdge 2970 still find HD's without RAID memory stick?

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge

So, I purchased a refurb P/E 2970, but the RAID RAM stick is missing.  When it boots, I get the error "RAID Adapter - Memory Error" (something like that).  I've tried using the "Server Assistant" and other "Server Admin" helpers, but they only get so far as the first Linux screen, then nothing more.  None of the 3 hard drives are being recognized.

Before I go deeper into trying to get this to work, I'd like to know if I'm wasting my time even trying before I get a memory stick in there.  Anyone know if this will work without the RAID RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controller is a PERC 5/i, it would not work without RAM. But you could easily just plug a [compatible 256 MB DDR2 module](http://www.overclock.net/t/359025/perc-5-i-raid-card-tips-and-benchmarks) to change that.

Comment: Yes, it's a PERC 5/i.  Unfortunately I don't have any spare RAM right now or I would have done just that. Thanks for the answer.